# efficient search for one of many substrings in a larger string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing

I'm looking for a function that finds a substring from an array of strings ('needles') in a longer string ('haystack').  Basically I want it to work like this example:

```
var haystack = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var needles = [
  'bcd',
  'pqr',
  'hi',
  'ghi',
  'g',
  'stuv'
  ];

var output = findSubstring (haystack, needles, 2, 20);
```

Output should now have:

```
 {index: 6, which: 3}
```

which means it found "ghi" (needle 3) at position 6.  It gets 'ghi' rather than 'hi', because 'ghi' starts earlier in the haystack, but it doesn't get 'g' because 'ghi' is earlier in the needles array.

This is the best that I have come up with, but it seems rather slow on very large chunks of text and very large needle arrays (which is what I am using it on), and I'm sure there is something better.  It is pretty performance critical stuff so I'd really like something faster.

I could imagine better ways to do it (probably not using indexOf), and since this is (presumably) a pretty common sort of thing to do, someone with more experience with this sort of thing might have a better way to go about it.  (i.e. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel)

```
function findSubstring (haystack, needles, startIndex, endIndex) {
  var min = Infinity, best = -1;
  var numNeedles = needles.length;
  if (!startIndex)
    startIndex = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<numNeedles; i++) {
    var index = haystack.indexOf(needles[i], startIndex);
    if (index != -1 && index < min) {
      min = index;
      best = i;
    }
  }
  return (best == -1 || (endIndex && best >= endIndex)) ?
      null : 
      {index: min, which: best};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest combining your needles into a single regex:  "bcd|pqr|hi|ghi|g|stuv".

The regular expression engine will combine those into a single, efficient finite state machine.

Comment: This is the sensible answer, and will run extremely fast.

Comment: Makes sense but I'm unsure how to tell which of the alternatives was matched -- but then again i'm no regex expert

Comment: @rob: if you can tell the alternatives apart [by their prefix, suffix or in entirety] as in your example) you use the regexp to find the hit, and check which one it is. if the regexps are very complex and have pattern matching rather than constants at both ends, you'll have a harder time, granted.

Comment: hmm, so I still have to walk through the needles array, and for each member, do a comparison of it to a substring of the haystack string?

Comment: No, run the regexp on the whole string.  Presumably it says, "matched at position N".  you check position N to see which case you have.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, I understand that, but I would still have to walk through the *needles* array, to compare it with a needles[i].length substring of haystack which starts at position N.

Comment: Right. But needles in 10 entries long, and haystack is a million and you only check on a place where one of the needle entries is known to match.  Your alternative is match needles against haystack[1], haystack[2], ...  which is pretty unappetizing.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm will find all of an arbitrary set of strings where they occur. The cost is the size of the string to be searched plus a constant amount per match found, plus a setup time that is linear in the size of the set of strings to be found. You would need to add extra logic to discard the matches you don't seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the substrings into separate arrays by first character... an array for words starting with 'a', another array for 'b', and so on.

Turn your string into an array.

Parse through the array, one character at a time, checking each relevant array of substrings for a match.  Use binary search to accelerate checking the substring arrays if that would improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `indexOf` over and over for every string that you are looing for, create an integer array where you store the result of calling `indexOf` once for each string.

After that you just locate the smallest number in the array (that is not -1), and that is the first match in the string. Then you just update the items in the array that are smaller than the character following the match (and not -1). Repeat until you reach the end of the string, or all items in the array are -1.

Comment: hmm maybe i don't understand but that seems to require the same number of indexOf calls (one per member of needles)

Comment: @rob: It requires a lot less `indexOf` calls as you are keeping the results instead of starting over for each match. Instead of O(n*m) where n is the number of needles and m is the number of matches, you get something closer to O(n+m).

Comment: I think you must be talking about calling the function findSubstring() in a loop....in which case what you say makes sense.  Otherwise, findSubstring calls indexOf() needles.length times.

Comment: @rob: I see... You want only the *first* occurance from only *part* of the string, and the output should not *have* but *only contain* the object in the example? I assumed that you wanted to find *all* occurances, and that the object in the example would be one of the objects that the result would have.

Answer (score 0):

If the heyStack is going to be a very large text then it "might" be better to cut off the rest of the heyStack every time a needle is found:

```
if (index != -1 && index < min) {
    min = index;
    best = i;
    hayStack = hayStack.substring(0, index + indles[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm, it might be useful for your problem